# Share XCode provisioning profile to build on multiple computers

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have an iOS project I want to be able to build and sign on two
different Macs, and test on two different iPhones. I've added the
provisioning profile to Xcode Organizer on the second machine, and
added the UDID for the second iPhone to "use for development" on that
machine.

Now the profile is in XCode Organizer but not available as a choice in
**XCode -> Build Settings -> Code Signing**. When I try to run the
project, I get the error "No unexpired provisioning profiles found
that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates".

I've tried deleting and reinstalling the profile, but I haven't been
able to add it to XCode Code Signing. I've also tried synchronizing
the second iPhone via iTunes to install the profile on the phone,
but without success.

How can I use the same provisioning profile on both machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask him to send you the assicated certificate (as .p12 file) with that provisioning profile install that certificate in key chain access by double clicking it and then entering the password he has created while exporting certificate as .p12 file . IF  that profile was made with that certificate you should be able to select code signing identity in build settings

Comment: Does this certificates signed to a particular computer?

Comment: Each of the profile has it own associated certificate.That is needed for signing the code

Comment: We are made export from his keychain access and import to keychain on my computer (.p12 file as you said). But still nothing works. What else can be wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's a horribly dumb one. Before importing certificate and profile we should have deleted the old ones from Xcode and Keychain. Now everything worked. Sad that thread is closed because someone can save a lot of time with this issue.

Comment: FWIW (ca. 2020) this is no longer necessary — you can [export / import developer accounts](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev8a2822e0b) from the XCode Accounts preferences.